# Rename files based on their parent directory using find/xargs command?

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, find, rename

I have a directory structure like this:

```
Project/
  |
  +--Part1/
  |    |
  |    +--audio.mp3
  |
  +--Part2/
  |    |
  |    +--audio.mp3
  |
  +--Part3/
  |    |
  |    +--audio.mp3
...
```

I want to end up with files called Part1.mp3, Part2.mp3, etc.

Each folder only contains a single file so there is no risk of clobbering files or dealing with multiple files with the same name.

I feel like I could do this with some sort of `find`/`xargs` command coupled with `cut` and `mv` but I can't figure out how to actually form the command.

Comment: If you're willing to use `zsh`, `zmv '(*)/audio.mp3' '$1.mp3'`

Answer (score 12):

These examples work in any POSIX shell and require no external programs.

This stores the Part*.mp3 files at the same level as the Project directory:

```
(cd Project && for i in Part*/audio.mp3; do echo mv "$i" ../"${i%/*}".mp3; done)
```

This keeps the Part*.mp3 files in the Project directory:

```
for i in Project/Part*/audio.mp3; do echo mv "$i" ./"${i%/*}".mp3; done
```

These solutions use the shell's `pattern matching` `parameter expansion` to produce the new filename.

> ```
>  ${parameter%word}     Remove Smallest Suffix Pattern.  The word is expanded
>                        to produce a pattern.  The parameter expansion then
>                        results in parameter, with the smallest portion of
>                        the suffix matched by the pattern deleted.
> ```

Comment: oh yeah. i guess that proviso was dumb. sorry. it got my vote, though. i think `mv -i` would at least prompt if the target already exists, too, maybe.

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks for the fixes.  I didn't want to get into `mv -i` etc because the question said "no risk of clobbering files" etc, although I often like to use `mv -i`.

Comment: Why the `..` in the first version?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, because the shell has temporarily changed directory to the Project directory.  The reason for the chdir is to simplify the new name generation.  If there was no `cd Project`, then another step would be required inside the loop to remove the `Project/` prefix.  The change directory is "temporary" because the entire command is enclosed in parenthesis `()`, effectively creating a sub-shell.  After the command  completes, the current shell's directory is the same as before the parenthesized command.

Comment: Doesn't the `..` in the `mv` move the files to the level above the Project directory — at the same level as the name Project, rather than the directory holding the various Part directories?  Try this script in a directory where you do not have a valuable sub-directory `junk`. It places the '.mp3' files one level too far up the directory hierarchy when I run it: `rm -fr junk/Project;
mkdir -p junk/Project;
(cd junk/Project; mkdir Part{1,2,3}; for d in Part?; do echo > $d/audio.mp3; done);
du -a junk;
(cd junk/Project && for i in Part*/audio.mp3; do mv "$i" ../"${i%/*}".mp3; done);
du -a junk;`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, In the first example, and with your example, the MP3 files are moved to `junk/Part*.mp3`.  In the second example, the files are moved to `Project/Part*.mp3` (or `junk/Project/Part*.mp3` in your example directory structure.)  When I run your script in an empty directory, near the end of the output I see 'junk/Part1.mp3`, `junk/Part2.mp3` and `junk/Part3.mp3`.  Isn't that what you see?

Comment: OK; we're in agreement about the result of your script.  I'm no longer sure from the question where the files were expected to be.  I interpreted it as 'files in the `Project` directory'; you as 'files in the parent of the `Project` directory'.  The difference is minimal (it could be as simple as 'remove one of the `.` characters'), so let's assume you got it right.  Sorry to bug you over nothing.  Lemme know if you want me to remove my comments; there's no problem if you do.  Meanwhile, Happy New Year.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Yes the question does not specify the final location of the MP3 files, which is why this answer contains two examples.  The confusion seems to be the result of the unclear question.  Thanks for your feedback and Happy New Year to you too!

Answer (score 7):

If you have the perl `rename` (sometimes called `prename`) you can do this:

```
( cd Project && rename 's!(.+)/(.+)(\.mp3)!$1.$3!' */audio.mp3 )
```

This takes each filename matching the shell glob `*/audio.mp3` and splits it into the directory, filename, and extension components. It then discards the filename part and renames the file.

Use `rename -n ...` to see what would happen, or use `-v` instead of `-n` to watch it happening as it runs.

Answer (score 3):

```
pax -rwls'|.*/\(.*\)/audio\(\.mp3\)$|\1\2|p' \
    -s'|.*||' /path/to/Project .
```

That will use the POSIX `pax` command-line archiver utility to make hardlinks in the current directory named like `parent_dirs_base.mp3` for every `audio.mp3` found rooted in the tree at *`/path/to/Project`*. While doing so it will print any filename modifications it makes to stderr.

Use `-k` to prevent it possibly overwriting existing files with identical names as its link targets, or, and better yet, first change to an empty directory before running it.

In my opinion, there is a significant advantage to hardlinking first rather than directly `mv`ing the files you seek to work with: and that is that you get the chance to verify that the results you expect are the same as those you get *before* removing originals. When you have checked you can:

```
find /path/to/Project -name audio.mp3 -exec rm {} +
```

...to clean up and cut the file links down by one.

Comment: I do wish I could get my head around `pax`. I keep forgetting to use it, though. Happy New Year mikeserv.

Comment: @roaima - happy new years to you! `pax` is pretty easy - `s` for substitute, `r` for read *(extract)*, `w` for write *(archive)*, `l` for link, and `p` for preserve permissions. to copy *(or make hardlinks)* you just `r` and `w` at the same time. you do `pax -options [source[s]*] [destination?]`. it does tar files - just more simply. it can also read names on stdin - and it always writes to stdout by default. when you do substitutions if the result is a null string that file's left out, if the `s///` is otherwise successful the rest of the `-s` arguments are ignored. thats probably a lot of it

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

These are your files:

```
$ cd Project
$ find . -type f
./Part2/audio.mp3
./Part3/audio.mp3
./Part1/audio.mp3
```

Using `dirname` will return the name of their directory (assuming you only have one level of sub-directories). Thus:

```
$ find . -type f \
   | while read i ; do \
       d=$(dirname $i); echo renaming "$i" to "$d.mp3" ; \
     done
renaming ./Part2/audio.mp3 to ./Part2.mp3
renaming ./Part3/audio.mp3 to ./Part3.mp3
renaming ./Part1/audio.mp3 to ./Part1.mp3
```

And this will rename them:

```
$ find . -type f | while read i ; do d=$(dirname $i); mv "$i" "$d.mp3" ; done
```

Answer (score -1):

Bash with perl style

```
for file in `find . -type f -name "*.mp3"`;
    do
        dir=$(dirname $file);
        bdir=$(basename $dir);
        bname=$(basename $file);
        new=$bdir.$bname;
        newname=${new//\.\./};
        newname_with_path=$dir/$newname
        if [ "$file" != "$newname_with_path" ]
        then
            echo mv -u $file  $newname_with_path ;
        fi
    done


    # replace 2 dots with nothing
    # bash 4.1.2 centos 6.4 no problem with or without bashslash
    newname=${new//../};
```

Comment: in case bdir is a dot and I have a dot to concat bdir and bname which make 2 dots, not pretty, thanks for looking

Comment: @RobertL, I edited and add more info to it, it is the bash version?

Comment: Sorry!  I made a mistake.  I didn't run it with `bash`.  It works.  Thanks.

Comment: I deleted my incorrect statements because it could cause confusion for other readers.  Please delete your comments if you think appropriate.  Thanks for the explanation.